# Why is $V^{\perp}={0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $V$ be an inner product space. I have read a statement saying $V^{\perp}=\{0\}$. Why is this true? It seems trivial to even define an orthogonal complement to $V^{\perp}$ if it is always just $0$.

Thank you!

Comment: Since $V^{\perp}$ is a set, we should really say "$V^{\perp} = \{ 0 \}$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be an inner product space. For a set $M \subseteq V$, we define
$$
M^\perp = \{y \in V: \langle y,x \rangle = 0 \quad \forall x \in M\}
$$
So, by that logic, we have
$$
V^\perp = \{y \in V: \langle y,x \rangle = 0 \quad \forall x \in V\}
$$
however, if $y \in V$, and $\langle y,x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in V$, then $\langle y,y \rangle = 0$.  So, the only element of $V^\perp$ is $0$.

Comment: Also, how does this notation read? In words (as if you were saying it out loud in person) would it read: the orthogonal complement is the set of all vectors $y$ in the vector space $V$ such that the inner product of $y$ and $x$ is $0$ for all $x$ in the subspace $V$?

Comment: You're right, I should have specified that $V$ is an inner product space

Comment: If I were reading it out loud, I would say that "the orthogonal complement of $M$ is the set of vectors $y$ in $V$ that are orthogonal to *every* vector $x$ in $M$".

Comment: Perfect, thanks again for yet ANOTHER answer :)

Comment: famous omnomnomnom eating up free reputation points on my easy questions LOL